# Ajax to get value in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using codeignitor framework and I'm very new to it so please help me out with my problem.

Below is the view:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url().'plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.2.0.min.js'?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url:'<?php echo site_url('ajax/hello/');?>',
            success:function(result){
                $('#value').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="container">
<p id="value"></p>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the controller:

```
<?php
class Ajax extends CI_Controller{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
    public function hello(){
        return 'hello';
    }
}
?>
```

I'm using ajax to get value from controller,Can anyone please help me how to do

Answer (score 1):

In the `hello()` function, try to `echo` the response instead of using `return` -

```
<?php
class Ajax extends CI_Controller{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('index');
    }
    public function hello(){
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Return will not do anything, you need to echo a response. Its also a good idea to echo a JSON response as that can be used directly by javascript as a native javascript object.

```
public function hello(){
    echo json_encode( array('reply' => 'hello');
}
```

Now if you change your AJAX call to tell it to expect a JSON response like this

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    dateType: 'json',
    url:'<?php echo site_url('ajax/hello/');?>',
    success:function(result){
        $('#value').html(result.reply);
    }
});
```